# how can I remove leding slashes in path before fastcgi pass without redirect in nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I would like to serve the same php app(Laravel) content from 
'example.com/test/...' and 
'example.com//test/...' I want to send 'example.com/test/...' to the app either way.

Below is excerpts from my current config for the server block in question

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME 
        $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

Comment: nginx will normalize your URI and automaticaly convert `//test/` to `/test/`.

Comment: I cannot test this, but you may be able to send Laravel a normalised URI. Try:  `fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $uri$is_args$args;` after including your other fastcgi params.